# VSTS release pipeline release gate: how to do HTTP response body string equality check?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to check whether my deployed ASP.NET application returns `Healthy` from health check endpoints or not.

Unfortunately, the success criteria samples of the "Invoke Rest API" release gate only show how to evaluate JSON responses like `eq(root['status'], 'successful')` or `eq(count(jsonpath('Items[?(@.price<50)]'))`.

As my endpoint doesn't return any JSON I wonder if it's possible to do a simple stupid string equality check somehow?

Of course I could rely on checking the HTTP status code, I feel like it should be possible to access the response body.

This is the exception I get when using `eq(root, "Healthy")`:

[image: log output when using eq root]

Comment: I just came across this issue with a private PR, not sure if related or not as I don't want to use the body as a variable outside the task: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/7581

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT for now we just rely on the check whether the endpoint returns a 200 OK (which means Healthy or Degraded) or 500 (Unhealthy) as it's not important enough for us to rewrite the health check backend to return valid JSON instead of text/plain (which it does by default). So the issue still persists, we just use this kind of workaround for now.

Comment: Much appreciate this workaround shared here. Since the root cause of this issue is that the success criteria doesn't support to compare the  regular string , maybe you could try to submit a feature request in our [user voice forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21). The team there would check your idea and consider about that.

Comment: Same issue as OP. It's odd this is not supported by default seeing as this is all Microsoft Code (Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks and Microsoft Azure Devops).

Answer (score 1):

If your endpoint returns just a string try simply this:

```
eq(root, 'SomeString')
```

This is really strange that you get such error. It works on my release pipeline:

Here is settings:
[image]

And here result:

[image]

Comment: It results in "Exception Message: Error parsing API response into a JSON object.".

Comment: It probably works for you because `"some"` is valid JSON, whereas `some` isn't. See my hint "my endpoint doesn't return any JSON" above.

Comment: You are right. So you know the answer. You may use `"Healthy"` as a hack or full json. Becuase regular string comparison is not possible. Good candidate for developer community. Thanks for a lesson!

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Krzysztof Madej

> Exception Message: Error parsing API response into a JSON object.

You could check the “URL suffix and parameters” field in “Invoke Rest API task”.

Please make sure that the whole URL is valid.

The whole URL contains the Server URL (Set in service connection) and the URL suffix and parameters (Set in Invoke Rest API task).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The server URL is valid and reachable. The log output also shows

`Response Code: OK; Response: Healthy; Evaluation of expression 'eq(root, 'Healthy')' failed.  Exception Message: Error parsing API response into a JSON object. (type DistributedTaskException)` - the server's response is a simple `Healthy` string with a `text/plain` content type. Krzysztof Madej had quotes around his string, which is valid JSON. Mine isn't.

Comment: I understood the difference and tested the text/plain content type. This indeed could cause this issue. It seems that  it can't compare the string value(text/plain content type). As Krzysztof said, you need to use the string as Json type.